# Show more or less with slice buttons disable or enable

Tags: javascript, jquery, slice

I have a jQuery slice function that loads more or less images. I am trying to alter this to hide or disable the button show more if no more images are available or if we have 6 images displayed hide the show less button.

I can get this to work with the show more button. however If i load the page and only 2 images display and no more available the show more button is still present.

Can someone please show me what I'm doing wrong and how to get it to work with the show less button.

**code**

```
 jQuery(document).ready(function ($) {
        const cards = $('.card-deck')
        let clicks = 9;

        if (cards.length > 9) {
            cards.hide();
            cards.slice(0, 9).show();
        }
        $('.show-more').on('click', function () {
            clicks = clicks + 6;
            if (clicks > cards.length) {
                clicks = cards.length
            }
            cards.slice(0, clicks).fadeIn();

            if ($(".card-deck :hidden").length == 0) {
                $(".show-more").hide();
            } else {
                $(".show-more").show();
            }
            e.preventDefault();
        });

        if (cards.length > 9) {
            $('.show-less').on('click', function () {
                clicks = clicks - 6;
                if (clicks < 0) {
                    clicks = 0
                }
                cards.slice(clicks, cards.length).fadeOut();
            });
        }
});
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to your code example you only hide "show more" button if there are no elements with .card-deck class, that match :hidden jQuery pseudo-class selector. And you only check that after each click on "show more" button. This is the first mistake. 
If you want to hide it beforehand, you need to check this conditions earlier, like you did here (which is also a good place to put logic for "show more" and "show less" buttons:

```
 if (cards.length > 9) {
            cards.hide();
            cards.slice(0, 9).show();
        }
```

**There are two important things here:**

1. Setting correct buttons' states at the beginning.
2. Noticing, that clicking on "show more" and "show less" affects the state of the other one.

You can wrap toggling buttons' state in separate function. Call it once, when DOM is loaded and then each time user clicks on any of these buttons. 
 Check carefully `toggleButtons` function.

```js
jQuery(document).ready(function($) {
    cardDeck('blue');
    cardDeck('red');
    cardDeck('green');
});

function cardDeck(id) {
    const cards = $(`#${id} .card-deck`)
    const showMoreButton = $(`#${id} .show-more`);
    const showLessButton = $(`#${id} .show-less`);
    const visibleCardsThresholdMin = 6;
    const step = 6;
    let numberOfVisibleCards = Math.min(cards.length, 9);

    cards.hide();
    cards.slice(0, numberOfVisibleCards).show();

    const toggleButtons = () => {
        if (numberOfVisibleCards == cards.length) {
            showMoreButton.hide();
        } else {
            showMoreButton.show();
        }

        if (numberOfVisibleCards <= visibleCardsThresholdMin) {
            showLessButton.hide();
        } else {
            showLessButton.show();
        }
    }

    toggleButtons();

    showMoreButton.on('click', function(e) {
        e.preventDefault();
        numberOfVisibleCards += step;
        if (numberOfVisibleCards > cards.length) {
            numberOfVisibleCards = cards.length
        }
        cards.slice(0, numberOfVisibleCards).fadeIn();
        toggleButtons();

    });

    showLessButton.on('click', function(e) {
        e.preventDefault();
        numberOfVisibleCards -= step;
        if (numberOfVisibleCards < visibleCardsThresholdMin) {
            numberOfVisibleCards = visibleCardsThresholdMin;
        }
        cards.slice(numberOfVisibleCards, cards.length).fadeOut();
        toggleButtons();

    });
}
```

```css
.container {
  width: 100%;
  min-height: 30px;
  margin-bottom: 10px;
}

.card-deck {
  width: 20px;
  height: 20px;
  border: 1px solid black;
  float: left;
  margin-right: 2px;
  margin-bottom: 2px;
}

#blue .card-deck {
  background-color: #63ace5;
}

#red .card-deck {
  background-color: #fe4a49;
}

#green .card-deck {
  background-color: #7bc043;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class ="container" id="blue">
  <div class="card-deck"></div>
  <div class="card-deck"></div>
  <div class="card-deck"></div>
  <div class="card-deck"></div>
  <div class="card-deck"></div>
  <div class="card-deck"></div>
  <div class="card-deck"></div>
  <button class="show-more">Show more</button>
  <button class="show-less">Show less</button>
</div>

<div class ="container" id="red">
  <div class="card-deck"></div>
  <div class="card-deck"></div>
  <div class="card-deck"></div>
  <div class="card-deck"></div>
  <div class="card-deck"></div>
  <div class="card-deck"></div>
  <div class="card-deck"></div>
  <div class="card-deck"></div>
  <div class="card-deck"></div>
  <div class="card-deck"></div>
  <div class="card-deck"></div>
  <div class="card-deck"></div>
  <div class="card-deck"></div>
  <div class="card-deck"></div>
  <div class="card-deck"></div>
  <div class="card-deck"></div>
  <div class="card-deck"></div>
  <div class="card-deck"></div>
  <div class="card-deck"></div>
  <div class="card-deck"></div>
  <div class="card-deck"></div>
  <div class="card-deck"></div>
  <div class="card-deck"></div>
  <div class="card-deck"></div>
  <div class="card-deck"></div>
  <div class="card-deck"></div>
  <div class="card-deck"></div>
  <div class="card-deck"></div>
  <div class="card-deck"></div>
  <div class="card-deck"></div>
  <div class="card-deck"></div>
  <div class="card-deck"></div>
  <div class="card-deck"></div>
  <div class="card-deck"></div>
  <div class="card-deck"></div>
  <button class="show-more">Show more</button>
  <button class="show-less">Show less</button>
</div>

<div class ="container" id="green">
  <div class="card-deck"></div>
  <div class="card-deck"></div>
  <div class="card-deck"></div>
  <div class="card-deck"></div>
  <div class="card-deck"></div>
  <div class="card-deck"></div>
  <button class="show-more">Show more</button>
  <button class="show-less">Show less</button>
</div>
```